# Laravel - Can't get input errors when using google recaptcha

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I'm using google recaptcha in my login form. I pasted script tag and the snippet in the login template and also added `'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',` to the array of `validateLogin` method in `AuthenticatesUsers.php`. when I submit the form, I only get error for recaptcha not email or password input! when I remove `'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',` I can get errors!

Comment: Laravel 8 sollution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720254/google-recaptcha-with-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to set up a new validator by yourself (not sure it would work, that's an idea).

Here is the link to this doc section: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators

And an example in a controller file attached to the action:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
}
```