# Form entry is not required although it is while using ReCaptcha v3 & Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I have some trouble working with laravel 8 & ReCaptcha.
I've a form, and inside it I've put a recaptcha v3. I want all my input required but when I press submit, only 2 of them are showing that I need to complete it (see the screen 1 below, sry its in french). When I put something inside the 2 input that tells me "YOU NEED TO WRITE SOMETHING THERE", and I submit then the form is working (even if I did not wite something on the others input which are normally required).

All my input have the required tag. The problem here come from the recaptcha button tag which is :

```
<button class="g-recaptcha btn" data-sitekey="myrecaptchakey" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit' >
```

When I remove the `class + date-sitekey + data-callback + data-action` and adding `type=submit` its working well (see the screen 2 below).

How can I resolve this using recaptcha please ?

Cordially

Screen 1 :

[image]

Screen 2 :

[image]

EDIT : So, I've put that just before my button : `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mycaptchakey"></div>` and then my button should be `<button class=" btn "  type="submit">` and there is the result : It says that the key is not working

[image]

Comment: this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720254/google-recaptcha-with-laravel/68431737#68431737

Comment: I'm doing the other way which is by importing `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`. You think thats why Its not working ?

Comment: @Balure. same script used in that answer also . only difference is you are using data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit' to verify separately. If not solved by that answer then here someone might help you to solve your issue

Comment: I've edited my first post (see at the end) with another way to do it.

Comment: .If you are using local then use test keys or else add your domain in repatcha google admin.in that post added few ref link you cna check that

Comment: Ok, its working with the test keys. But this is the v2 recaptcha (with the check thing) and not the v3 :( Since the v3 need to be inside the button I guess..

Comment: for version 3 try test in any valid domain names .it might work

Comment: Well, I just found out that for registration its better to use the v2. While for the login, search and so on, its better to use the v3. So I guess I'll use the v2. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hmmm, I've got another problem there. How can I say that the recaptcha should be required to register the form ? Because I can complete everything except the recaptcha and its still working